# Refresh tab content on click in JQuery tabs

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, tabs

Im having an issue with using tabs via Visual Composer for Wordpress, along with an extension for Visual Composer called Visual Composer Modal Popups.

Basically I have all my sub level pages loading in tabs, although it seems to not load any Jquery scripts needed for the content with in each tab, unless I refresh the page (in which they then seem to work fine).

Link: http://gjwalsh.marketingmatch.net.au/who_we_are-2/

"Team members" tab on the above page is the trouble.

Is there anyway I can force load or force refresh upon clicking a tab?

This way the content would appear correctly first time and not after manually refreshing the page. Or I'm open to any other suggestions as I am not that code savvy, any help is greatly appreciated in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll suggest load jquery and assign the id to that tab and on click function reload the page.

```
jQuery("#team").click(function() {  location.reload(true); });
```

Or Using Javascript with the help of onclick function

```
<a href="#tab-1403849707999-3-7" id="team" onClick="window.location.reload()">TEAM MEMBERS</a>
```

Comment: This sounds great in theory although if only I wasnt such a noob I could assign an id... any suggestions on how to go about that in wordpress?

Comment: Just find that html code and place it.It would be inside your theme folder.

Comment: The Java works although it reloads the whole page and starts off at the first tab again. Is there a way to reload only the tab content upon clicking the tab? or alternatively reloading the whole page but opening to the 'Team Members' tab

Thanks for your direction so far! Getting closer!

Comment: this should work `jQuery(function() {
      jQuery("#team").click(function(evt) {
        jQuery(".q_tabs horizontal").load("http://gjwalsh.marketingmatch.net.au/who_we_are-2/")
         evt.preventDefault();
      })
    })` But for this you must have to load jquery.

Comment: And for Javascript `function reload_div(){
document.getElementById("yourdivid").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="pageurl" ></object>';
}`

Comment: Thanks for all your help thus far! I think I'll be able to work out assigning the ID '#team' although my experience with editing jQuery is nill to none!

Do I create a new jquery file say via dreamweaver then upload this via ftp and then add it to the head tag of my php file?

or is it possible to add this function to an exciting jquery file that is already being loaded? (or am I so far from the mark that I should read a book? lol sorry graphic designer trying to be something im clearly not ha)

Comment: No need to make separate file for that just load this  `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` top of the current page.(Reference)[https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery]

Comment: wow , it is still valid for Chrome extension, inside injected.js.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Disabling AJAX on the pages with external plug-ins seemed to be the easiest way to fix this thanks to the theme developers.

Thanks for your help Roschach! Your suggestion did work although wasnt the solution I was after in the end.